# What does "_log" mean in pytables classes?

Tags: python, pytables

What does the `_log` parameter mean in pytables? The documentation doesn't seem to mention it at all. It defaults to `True`, but I have seen some examples where it is `False`.

**What is the result setting this to true or false?**

For reference, the parameter appears in:

- [Group](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/hierarchy_classes.html#tables.Group)
- [Leaf](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/hierarchy_classes.html#the-leaf-class)
- [CArray](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#carrayclassdescr)
- and many others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [source](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/8eebc51a9615a4721992b24422a1c4fe52120f13/tables/node.py#L201)

```
# The ``_log`` argument is only meant to be used by ``_g_copy_as_child()``
# to avoid logging the creation of children nodes of a copied sub-tree.
```

The docs don't mention it because it is not supposed to be interesting to external users.  By [convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles), Python names starting with an underscore (`_`) are meant to be "internal".

Comment: In the source for "node" is the only place that your quoted text appears. Does it mean the same for all of the other classes?

Comment: Those classes all inherit from `Node`.

Comment: I'll make a quick note, for PyTables, they deviate substantially from normal naming conventions so every child can be accessed as an attribute.

To avoid any conflicts, they use a similar naming convention as `namedtuple`s, which provide all methods with a leading underscore.

For PyTables, methods which start with `_f` are public, variables starting with `_v` are public instance variables, and methods starting with `_g` are internal methods.